# Can 2 or more LED strobe Lights Flash in Sync?

Tags: led, rtc, attiny13

I'm trying to build a strobe light that has at least 1 mode that can sync with another unit.

The strobe light has 2 colors, white and red which are driven by 2 qlite drivers which are controlled by an ATtiny13a processor.

The strobe light will be used on an ultralight aircraft. I want the ability to have the lights sync, so if there are a few aircraft flying, each strobe would be in sync and creating a better chance of being seen as a collective.

The easiest way to see this is from obstruction lights on windfarms. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb7MWrBEZjU  They are mandated by FAA to be in sync. I believe they achieve this by matching internal processor clock speeds with the GPS clock data.

Or could I use a Real Time Clock to time the processors together?

If I'm already using Qlite flashlight drivers which use ATtiny13 chips, is there any way I can get the different lights to sync?

The body is a standard flashlight body.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Using the 1PPS output of a GPS receiver seems to be the easiest way, just make sure to use an integral flash frequency.

Comment: Thank you! So would the GPS module interface my existing ATtiny13 processor via the 1PPS or would I need something else? Forgive my ignorance. Does the strobe pattern need to be simple flashes or would it be possible to sync any flashing pattern? Thanks again for your comment

Comment: Depends on whether the GPS modules need live interaction or if they can be preprogrammed to find satellites and output the signal. Any pattern, integral frequency.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so I'll need one that can connect automatically and send the pulse.

Comment: Something like this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14239

Comment: "The S1315F performs all the necessary system initialization, satellite signal acquisition & tracking, data demodulation, and calculation of navigation solution autonomously." Sounds like it should do.